# Create a csv file every hour?

Tags: c#, .net

I have to create a csv file every hour. I need to create a directory for the day and 
in the same directory for that day i have to create a file every hour

```
public string CreateFile()
{
    string rootDirectory = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BasePath"].ToString();
    string directoryName = "tracker-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"); 
    string fileName = "tracker-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") + ".csv"; //here i want the file to be for every hour
    string directoryPath=Path.Combine(rootDirectory, directoryName)
    string path = Path.Combine(directoryPath, filename);
    if (!Directory.Exists(directoryName))
    {
          Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryName);
    }

    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(path))
    {
        System.IO.File.Create(path).Dispose();
        using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path))
        {
            tw.WriteLine("New file created");
            tw.Close();
        }
    }
    return path;
}
```

Can any one please help me out here.

Comment: Use the windows task scheduler.

Comment: Hi, try to put the hour, minute and second components in your custom date time formatting:

string fileName = "tracker-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss MM-dd-yyyy") + ".csv"; //here i want the file to be for every hour

Hope I've helped!

Comment: Is your question _"How to run an executable every hour"_, or _"How to add the hour to the filename"_? Both have been answered before, try searching. @George's solution will not work for the latter, as you can't have colons (`:`) in filenames. And ignore the people saying to use a timer, that is very brittle. @Tim's solution is the correct one.

Comment: If you cant use Tim's answer, then create your code in a Class Library project if you haven't already and then add a windows service project to the solution and place it within a windows service. [Creating a windows service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Use `Quartz` library (preferably in combination with windows service)

Comment: I agree with @TimSchmelter's answer. If you build timer logic into your code then your code needs to always be running which means either a Windows Service or an app that sits on someone's desktop somewhere and is always running. Writing a Windows Service isn't too terribly hard but debugging them can be. And if you write a desktop app that just runs all the time you can pretty much guarantee that one day someone's going to reboot or sleep the computer or crash the process or whatever and you'll never realize that your app isn't working until much later.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you need an application to create a `csv` file every hour, then you can use a `Timer`

```
Timer _tmrCsv = new Timer { Interval = 3600000 };
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _tmrCsv.Tick += _tmrCsv_Tick;
    _tmrCsv.Enabled = true;

}

void _tmrCsv_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CreateFile();
}
```

Comment: your sample code will create a file every 60 hours!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Here is a sample code:

```
 private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;
 private static int counter = 0;
 private static void SetTimer()
{
    // Create a timer with a one minute interval.
    aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(60000);
    // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
    aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
    aTimer.AutoReset = true;
    aTimer.Enabled = true;
}

  private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    //Increment the counter
     counter++;

     if (counter== 60)
     {
        // One hour has passed
        // Reset the counter and create your file
        counter = 0;
        CreateFile();
     }
}
```

Comment: How do i get the current hour then

Comment: @SoftwareNerd **DateTime.Now.Hour**

Comment: Why not just use Timer with 1 hour interval?